# Emulate Excel column locking within scrolling container using only CSS without Javascript

Tags: html, css, html-table, position, css-float

Lots of posts about this but I believe what I'm asking for is just slightly different.

The layout is a list in table structure (I could use DIVs instead if needed to meet this need). The table structure will have multiple columns and multiple rows.

The goal is to literally make a table structure that works exactly like Excel column locking. I know this sounds familiar to a number of threads but here is the catch:
This means that when I scroll horizontally (left and right), those columns in the table will stay where they are... BUT when I scroll vertically (up and down) I need the columns to scroll with the page so that they are always lined up with the row they belong to.

Absolutely positioned DIVs freeze when I scroll in any and all directions, not just horizontally, and without JavaScript I can't dynamically adjust top positions. I know how to accomplish this using JavaScript, but that solution is hinged on the scroll event of the container and there could potentially be *hundreds* of rows to dynamically adjust as the user scrolls, which drains the CPU.

How can I accomplish this without JavaScript? And no, I don't want to use the Internet Explorer "expression()" in CSS as that's basically JavaScript ;)

It would be my preference to be cross browser compatible here, but I'd settle for IE only if that's necessary.

Comment: if you end up using javascript you can always [throttle](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) the scroll handler to reduce load.

Comment: but throttling the handler would result in the dynamic movement of the potentially hundreds of rows being lagged and possibly not lining up correctly if the user scroll down quickly.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use a nested Iframe for the table data, with the header remaining in the the 1st level of Iframe, allowing you to scroll horizontally, and an inner Iframe, allowing you to scroll vertically.

Comment: The problem with iFrames is that this table contains inputs within a form that I need to be able to submit back to the database for updating. Additionally, it may be problematic getting the table structure from two different frames to line up side-by-side. The goal is to have it all on the same page, that's why I listed only CSS in the title. But if this ends up not being possible, an iFrame is an option I'll have to look further into.

Comment: An Iframe will not prevent your ability to post back to the server. And, yes, this may be tricky to set up.

Comment: I'd have to move the DB save code into the iframe, so the user would also have to scroll down to find the save button. Additionally, an iFrame wouldn't automatically scroll up and down with the container without javascript either.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't appear to be possible without script. Ended up having to write custom javascript to accommodate. Didn't use inline frames, used DIV with overflow:scroll and linked into the onscroll event. Wish there was an easier way!